# get the product instance from catalog_product_attribute_update_after event

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, product-attribute

I'm listening to the **catalog_product_attribute_update_after** event and I want to get the product that is being updated.

I tried the following ($obs is the observer instance):

```
    Mage::log("getProduct " . !is_null($obs->getProduct()));
    Mage::log("getEvent " . !is_null($obs->getEvent()->getProduct()));
    Mage::log("getItem " . !is_null($obs->getItem()));
    Mage::log("registry " . !is_null(Mage::registry('product')->getData()));
```

But checking the logs show me that they all return null!

So how am I suppose to know which product is being updated inside the **catalog_product_attribute_update_after** observer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$productIds= $obs->getEvent()->getProductIds();
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```